# How to branch single Dev folder to different environments in QA in TFS

Tags: version-control, tfs, branching-and-merging

This is how I want the structure. When I branch from dev to Different QA environments. I want one environment to have exact same folder structure as dev, but the other QA environment shouldn't have the conversion tools folder within the installation folder from the dev folder as shown below.

- DEV(main folder)

  - Source code
  - Installation

    - setup file
    - conversion tools
  - Documents
- QA(1st environment)

  - Source code
  - Installation

    - setup file
    - conversion tools
  - Documents
- QA(2nd environment)

  - Source code
  - Installation

    - setup file
  - Documents

How can I set up this type of branches?

Comment: If this is not possible how else can it be done?